# New with php two dimensional array

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am having 2 problems with this two dimensional array, any help on how to solve them, I will appreciate.

The value on $data[3][1]; $data[3][2]; $data[3][3]; and $data[3][4]; are returning me 0 instead of the subtraction I want to make.

```
<?php
$data = array( 
array("Factor 1",16500,10000,100,100),
array("Factor 2",3000,1209,800,2765),
array("Factor 3 3",0,1000,1000,1000),
array("Factor 4",($data[0][1]-$data[1][1]),($data[0][2]-$data[1][2]),($data[0][3]-$data[1][3]),$data[0][4]-$data[1][4])
); 

echo $data[3][1];
?>
```

The next problem is that I want to print this array with a loop and I need it to look like this,

> ```
> <table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
>   <tr>
>     <td width="95">Factor 1</td>
>     <td width="15%">16500</td>
>     <td width="15%">10000</td>
>     <td width="15%">1000</td>
>     <td width="15%">100</td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td>Factor 2</td>
>     <td width="15%">3000</td>
>     <td width="15%">1209</td>
>     <td width="15%">800</td>
>     <td width="15%">2765</td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td>Factor 3</td>
>     <td width="15%">0</td>
>     <td width="15%">1000</td>
>     <td width="15%">1000</td>
>     <td width="15%">1000</td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>     <td>Factor 4</td>
>     <td width="15%">???</td>
>     <td width="15%">???</td>
>     <td width="15%">???</td>
>     <td width="15%">???</td>
>   </tr>
> </table>
> ```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested: link: https://eval.in/83247

```
$data = array(
        array("Factor 1",16500,10000,100,100),
        array("Factor 2",3000,1209,800,2765),
        array("Factor 3 3",0,1000,1000,1000),
        );
$aa = array("Factor 4",($data[0][1]-$data[1][1]),($data[0][2]-$data[1][2]),($data[0][3]-$data[1][3]),$data[0][4]-$data[1][4]);
array_push($data,$aa);
```

For second:

```
$output = '<table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">';
foreach ($data as $dat) {
     $output .= ' <tr>
     <td width="95">'.$dat[0].'</td>
     <td width="15%">'.$dat[1].'</td>
     <td width="15%">'.$dat[2].'</td>
     <td width="15%">'.$dat[3].'</td>
     <td width="15%">'.$dat[4].'</td>
     </tr>';
}
$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;
```

Comment: Did you try this? @Vohyndra

Comment: @Vohyndra Ask a different question if you're having a different problem, even a related problem, but **don't** edit this answer.  That isn't how SO works.

Comment: ok Awlad im sorry in new on SO. i add a new question.. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpfull.,

You can't use the array values while initialization

```
<?php

$data = array();

$data[] = array("Factor 1",16500,10000,100,100);
$data[] = array("Factor 2",3000,1209,800,2765);
$data[] = array("Factor 3 3",0,1000,1000,1000);
$data[] = array("Factor 4",($data[0][1]-$data[1][1]),($data[0][2]-$data[1][2]),($data[0][3]-$data[1][3]),$data[0][4]-$data[1][4]);

echo $data[3][1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$data = array( 
array("Factor 1",16500,10000,100,100),
array("Factor 2",3000,1209,800,2765),
array("Factor 3 3",0,1000,1000,1000),

); 
$data[]=array("Factor 4",($data[0][1]-$data[1][1]),($data[0][2]-$data[1][2]),($data[0][3]-$data[1][3]),$data[0][4]-$data[1][4]);
echo $data[3][1];
?>
```